# Why do 18650 batteries with lesser capacity (mAh) produce higher Amps?

Tags: batteries, amperage

Sony VTC4 IMR 18650 High Drain Flat top (2100mAh, 30A)

Sony VTC5A IMR 18650 High Drain Flat top (2600mAh, 25A)

LG HG2 INR18650 High Drain Flat Top (3000mah, 20A)

Sony VTC6 IMR 18650 High Drain Flat top (3000mAh, 15A)

Would it not be vice versa?

Comment: Makes sense to me. Thicker conductors for higher currents implies less space for the chemical reagents which give capacity.

Answer (score 1):

The energy density (capacity per volume) of a battery is a result of chemical and structural requirements which stand in direct contradiction to power density (I.e. high current capability per volume). Those being primarily high electrolytic volume vs high electrode surface area.

Also, high-current leads to high-temperature. And that is all the riskier the higher your capacity is - hence, reliability and ruggedness is another contradicting requirement.

Of course, cost plays a role, too.

Thus, it's either very expensive or impossible to get high-capacity batteries that are also high-current.

Answer (score 1):

It is an optimization problem. You can optimize batteries for capacity and for ESR (which limits the maximum current). But unfortunately, these two are coupled in complex ways and there is an upper limit how much you can decrease the ESR while increasing the capacity, and vice versa (much simplified to the point its not accurate anymore: for high capacity you need thin foils as conductor to increase surface per volume. But a thin foil has a higher resistance than a thick foil). Thus if a battery is optimized for capacity only, it's ESR will be high and thus the output current will be limited. If a battery is optimized for ESR (and high output current) then the capacity will suffer.